# How to open a text file in D drive containing insert statements in SQL Plus

Tags: sqlplus

I am using @/d/i.txt; syntax to open the file, but it is giving me error of:unable to open file "/d/i.txt".

Comment: Does the file (at that location) exist? Does the process have the permissions to read the file?

Comment: @Joel Bodenmann....Yes

Comment: @/i.txt; this works for C drive... but I have to read file from d drive.